# System command not being executed on server C++ CGI Windows IIS Server

Tags: c++, iis, cgi

I am setting up a server from my computer, and I got everything running, however I have a issue where the server will not execute system(), the website just freezes and does not execute.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() {
    std::cout << "Content-Type:text/html\n" << std::endl;
    system("start cmd");
}
```

No errors in compilation, but the server wont execute it when visiting the page. It just freezes. How can I fix this?

Comment: `system()` is a rats nest of security problems. I'd advice not to use it - *ever*.

Comment: I dont care about the issues I have a class too protect and authenticate everything. I *NEED* too find out why it is not working cause the program I am building depends on a program on my computer.

Comment: I usually dont use system but the program needs to be executed on the server.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?  You are telling it to execute an interactive shell through an HTTP transaction.  Why not try something that executes a command and returns some content.

Comment: This is obviously not the actual program this is what I was trying in the compiler, but it wont work. How do I fix this? System() Does not work at all. But if I do it from PHP then it works absolutely fine. But I dont have PHP in the IISSystem(); I only have it in the XamppSystem();

Comment: All I need to know is how to run system without it freezing and why it is freezing in the first place.

Comment: Can you start a process with `CreateProcess`? At the very least you may get a useful error message.

Comment: From the winapi?

Comment: I did not, in fact I did not know I could use WinAPI with CGI applications.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: That was just a "Hey, try this!" suggestion from the peanut gallery, not an answer. It's just the first place I'd go after `system`. Actually I'd probably try it before `system` if I was running in a service.

Comment: Did not work, just ended up freezing again.

Comment: Now system() is working in xampp... but not in IIS.. maybe its an issue with the IIS User Permissions?